# How can I render an Angular2 component to a string?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I would like to be able to use the Angular2 template syntax when building a [Google Maps InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

As far as I can tell, this means passing a a component as a template string to the `content` property in the `InfoWindow` constructor object.

If this is the case, I believe I need to stringify the component template. Is this correct (and possible)?

Here is an example of what I *think* I need to do:

```
// Component

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Thing} from './something/in/my/app/thing.model.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-infowindow',
  template: `<p>This is an infowindow for {{ something.name }}</p>`
})
export class MyInfoWindowComponent {
    constructor(public something: Thing) {}
}


// Implementation

import {Thing} from './something/in/my/app/thing.model.ts';
import {MyInfoWindowComponent} from './path/to/infowindow.component';

/* { ...stuff... } */

private _buildInfoWindow(thing: Thing): google.maps.InfoWindow {
    return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      /* v this is what I want v */
      content: new MyInfoWindowComponent(thing).toString() 
      /* ^ this is what I want ^ */
    });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `ElementRef` : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html or `ViewChild` : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html

Comment: I can't see the point of creating an Angular component and then stringify it to pass it to infowindow. Why don't you just pass a string instead. Is it because you want to use data-binding? This won't be updated after passing it to infowindow anyway.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - right, I don't need the databinding - the template sytax just seems much nicer than an awful stringbuilder. (especially for `ngIf` and `ngFor`). Does that make sense?

Comment: You could use `ElementRef` like @Langley explained and use `innerHTML`. Using Angular as string template builder is extremely inefficient compared to stringbuilder.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yuck. the warning in the docs makes me feel weird about that. And if it really has poor performance I probably will not use it, but if you would like to post an implementation of that as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Langley same thing I mentioned ^ applies to you.

Comment: Yea, that's why I put an alternative. but I don't it matters, the reason why it is not recommended its because you are supposed to change the virtual dom and let angular handle the real dom, but pretty much 99% of the libraries you'll find right now work off the real DOM so if you want to use them there's no really other option.

Comment: @Langley for sure. I just meant - it still technically answers my question, so I will mark it as accepted if you want to do the legwork.

Comment: @drewwyatt So how do you finally resolved this task? Please, share your approach. Im facing the same issue and I would like to use angular components for different InfoWindow templates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the `ElementRef` angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html.

Or something with `ViewChild`:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html

I will not write the code for you, but the idea is something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-infowindow',
  template: `<p #kiddo>This is an infowindow for {{ something.name }}</p>`
})
export class MyInfoWindowComponent {
    @ViewChild('kiddo') viewChild;
    constructor(public something: Thing) {}
    ngOnInit(){
        yourFunction(this.viewChild); //or viewChild.innerHtml or w/e works
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear. How do I inject compiled HTML from component viewChild property to google.maps.InfoWindow content:string?